# How to calculate the number of vertices contracted into one graph?

Tags: r, igraph

I have a few large `igraph` objects that represent social networks. All nodes have various attributes, among them `sector` which is a factor variable. I have contracted this large network into a small where vertices represent groups and edges have the sum of individual edges in the original network. The `label` attribute in the second network represents the `sector` attribute in the first.

```
groupnet <- contract(g, as.integer(as.factor(V(g)$sector)), "ignore")
E(groupnet)$weight <- 1
groupnet <- simplify(groupnet, edge.attr.comb = list(weight = "sum"))
V(groupnet)$label <- levels(as.factor(V(g)$sector))
```

I would like to add another attribute to the second object `V(groupnet)$groupsize` that represents the number of original vertices that were contracted into `groupnet`. I have tried it with the following code but it did not work:

```
  V(groupnet)$groupsize <- length(V(g)$sector[V(g)$sector == V(groupnet)$label])
```

How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`table()` could be helpful here. Try out:

```
set.seed(1234)
library(igraph)
g <- make_ring(1000)
V(g)$sector <- factor(sample(LETTERS, 100, replace = T))
V(g)$sector
## contracted network
groupnet <- contract(g, as.integer(as.factor(V(g)$sector)), "ignore")
E(groupnet)$weight <- 1
V(groupnet)$label <- levels(as.factor(V(g)$sector))
## number of original vertices that were contracted into groupnet
# the tip is to see that table(V(g)$sector) provides the number of vertices per sector and
# its output is also arranged like V(groupnet)
table(V(g)$sector)
V(groupnet)
# solution
V(groupnet)$groupsize <- as.numeric(table(V(g)$sector))
```